# How to go to second page with page transition in flutter?

Tags: flutter, transition, flutter-dependencies

I have used the transition.dart library and also made a transition dart file but I am always getting transition when I am coming back from the second page to the first page. But I need transition when I am going to the second page.

My code is:

```
 Navigator.push(context,PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.scale,child:Calculator()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by adding `Duration()` like below code:

```
Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.scale,child:Registration(),duration: Duration(seconds: 5)));
```

Use Below Dependency:

```
dependencies:
  page_transition: '^1.0.9'
```

You can also use other animations as below.

```
Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.upToDown, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.downToUp, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.scale, alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.size, alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rotate, duration: Duration(second: 1), child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade, child: DetailScreen()));

Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRightWithFade, child: DetailScreen()));
```

**Types of transitions**

- fade
- rightToLeft
- leftToRight
- upToDown
- downToUp
- scale (with alignment)
- rotate (with alignment)
- size (with alignment)
- rightToLeftWithFade,
- leftToRightWithFade

Comment: Thank you so much #Darshan Kunjadiya. After adding the duration, it's working properly.  please ping me on skype: sagardhiman5_1  . It would be a pleasure to connect you.